# Any known causes for high CPU when running JavaScript inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, iframe, cpu-usage

For my current project, a large piece of javaScript/jQuery is running for a long period of time (Many, many days). It has been tested in Chrome/Firefox/Internet Explorer.

Surprise surprise: It only breaks in Internet Explorer. It also only breaks when the piece of code is running inside an iframe.

The symptoms are slow to appear: it normally takes 8/10 hours for the CPU to creep up into it has taken over 100% of the thread it is running on. I am therefore having trouble finding ways to debug it.

**Question:** **Are there any known bugs/gimmicks that cause internet explorer to slow down when running JavaScript inside an iframe?**

Here is a rough run through of what my code does, It's very rough and SUDO-ish..

```
function setup() {

    readXML1(); // Ajax. Done once. Calls parseXML1() -> Creates array of variables.
    readXML2(); // Ajax. This repeats every 750ms. Sets a variable with the new "packet".
    readXML3(); // Ajax. Done once.Calls parseXML3() -> Creates array of variables.
    readXML4(); // Ajax. This repeats every 750ms. Sets a variable with the new "packet"

    bindSomeButtons(); // Create some toggling divs

    main();
}

function main() {
    var i, i2;

    parseXML1(); //  Checks for new packets. Creates/updates exampleObj's. These objects access the DOM.
    parseXML2(); // Checks for new packets. If so, this information updates an object, which accesses the DOM, including a table element.

    Settings.update();  // There .update() calls, use information supplied by readXML1/2 through parseXML1/2 to update stuff on the page.
    Connection.update();
    OtherStuff.update();

    for( i=0, i2 = gArr.Graphs.length; i<i2; i++ ) {
        Graphs[ i ].update(); // Uses information from readXML1 & parseXML1...
    }

    resizeParent(); // This calls parent.resize() with the calculates size of the iframe.

    setTimeout(main, 750);
};

var exampleObj = function( name, value ) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
    this.elem = $("."+name+", #"+name);
};

exampleObj.prototype.update = function( value ) {
    if( this.value != value ) {
        this.value = value;
        this.changeDOM(); // 
    }
};

exampleObj.prototype.changeDOM = function() {
    this.elem.empty().html( this.value );
}
```

Comment: Have tried to make a profile, that you can spot the bottlenecks or memory leaks?

Comment: Can you obfuscate some portions, change variable names, or replace some blocks with comments so that enough code to see what could be causing the problem can be shared? Try to reproduce the issue with 'generic' code.

Comment: I'm trying to do that now. Sorry, I realise this question wasn't up to the quality of SO. It'll take me sometime, I still need to track down roughly what's causing the problem. Going to try and speed up timers, etc. See if that causes the problem to show itself faster.

Comment: There's nothing special about running code inside an iframe, unless the code itself checks for being in an iframe and executes differently.

Comment: @Barmar Thats pretty helpful. Thank you. I'll scan through and see if there are any places this occurs. The fact still remains this only occurs in IE...

Comment: @Barmar: Well, if there is any cross-frame communication there might a bug that trips garbage collection and creates a memory leak.

Comment: @Bergi Just a quick note: I've had problems with memory leaks before, but [*fingers crossed*] solved them. The memory is pretty damn stable now. Its the CPU that's causing problems. The only time I've ever had something like this happen was when I was using jQuery to manipulate a table often (IE10 didn't like that, something to do with rendering the graphics).. But I solved that too.

Comment: Well, you say that the cpu level is slowly rising. This sounds like a leak (of what ever sort) to me.

Comment: That's very true. Sorry; I just wanted to make the point that the problems in the CPU, not perceived memory usage. I'm running some more tests now. I will track this bug (feature?) down now and destroy it!

Comment: Did you found out anything ?